# How to limit the times a BGProcessingTaskRequest is called?

Tags: ios, swift, background-process

Using the code below I'm attempting to limit the times that a `BGProcessingTasRequest` is called.  I don't need it to run multiple times a day, only once and I want to be respectful to the user's battery life.  However in testing the code, it never runs (even when substituting one hour for one day).  If I comment out the guard statement then the task gets scheduled several times an hour.  Is there a logical error here, or something I am not thinking of? (I know that when the processing task fires my `Date` is saving to `UserDefaults` properly).

```
private func schedulePersonalRecordsProcessingTask() {

    let request = BGProcessingTaskRequest(identifier: "com.myndarc.personalRecordsProcessing")
    request.requiresNetworkConnectivity = true 
    request.requiresExternalPower = false

    request.earliestBeginDate = Date(timeIntervalSinceNow: 60) 

    //Only update PRs no more than once a day
    let now = Date()
    let oneDay = TimeInterval(24 * 60 * 60)

    let lastBGTaskUpdateDate = defaults.value(forKey: backgroundTaskForPRLastDateKey) as? Date ?? .distantPast

    guard now > (lastBGTaskUpdateDate + oneDay) else {
        return 
    }

    do {
        try BGTaskScheduler.shared.submit(request)
    }
    catch {
        print("Could not schedule app refresh: \(error)")
    }
}
```

Comment: Your problem is that you are responsible for scheduling the task. If you don't, then it won't run. If the `guard` is met then you don't schedule the task. What you need to do is, when your task runs, determine the earliest you want the task to run again (say tomorrow) and specify that as the `earliestBeginDate`. Your code currently sets `earliestBeginDate` to 60 seconds after the start of time. Note that it is a `Date`- an absolute point in time, not an interval.

Comment: Im not sure I follow, would it make more sense if `earliestBeginDate` is `lastBGTaskUpdateDate + oneDay?` 

Comment: Yes, exactly,  that is the earliest date, not the earliest period from. That that you want the task to execute.

Comment: How it will work I am not able to get function called.